# Avoiding duplicate style properties when styling my JSX content?

Tags: reactjs

I'm styling some content in React using the inline styles approach. Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
var textStyles = {
  emphasis: {
    fontSize: 38,
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
  },
  smallEmphasis: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0
  },
  small: {
    fontSize: 17,
    opacity: 0.5,
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0
  }
}

return(
  <div style={divStyle}>
    <LightningCounter/>
    <h2 style={textStyles.smallEmphasis}>LIGHTNING STRIKES</h2>
    <h2 style={textStyles.emphasis}>WORLDWIDE</h2>
    <p style={textStyles.small}>(since you loaded this example)</p>
  </div>
);
```

One of the things that bothers me is that I am repeating the properties for `margin` and `padding` in my `emphasis`, `smallEmphasis`, and `small` objects. Since cascading isn't possible (AFAIK), is there a clean solution that doesn't involve me duplicating code?

Thanks,
Kirupa

Comment: Just curious your reasons for choosing inline styles, as far as I am aware they should only be used as a last resort. Besides using normal css you could refer to this: https://medium.com/@jviereck/modularise-css-the-react-way-1e817b317b04

Comment: It seems like inline styles is part of the "react way" to ensure that components are self-contained with all of their visual details in one place. I personally have no problem using normal CSS in general by tagging my JSX with className values :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using `ES6`, this seems like a candidate for the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) :

```
const baseStyle = {
   margin: 0,
   padding: 0
}

const emphasis {
  ...baseStyle,
  fontSize: 38
}
```

Better yet, in the spirit of `DRY`, if you find yourself repeating the same `baseStyle` from component to component, it might be worth separating it out to another file which can then be imported wherever needed:

**styles.js**

```
export default {
   margin: 0,
   padding: 0
}
```

**SomeComponent.jsx**

```
 import style from './styles
```

Answer (score 0):

It's JavaScript so just use regular object extension techniques either with a library like Underscore (if using ES5) or with Object.assign if it's available to you (using ES6) or polyfills.

```
var baseStyles = {
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0
},
emph = Object.assign(baseStyles, {
    font-size: 12px
});
```